# iterate object keys using *ngFor in Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to iterate the "others" with *ngFor
I got the "id" and "year" correct
but when I try to iterate "others", I got [object object]

```
 {
        "id": 11,
        "year": [
        2019,
        2020
        ],
        "others": {
        "name": "John",
        "age": "19",
        "work": "yes",
        },
    }
```

Comment: you will get [object object] since its not a single  key and value its and Object to get the Others you need to iterate through the Others again or if you need Others as string try Json Pipe.

Comment: @Krishna Kanth Could you please give example of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, By using the safe navigation `?`  So it will be `data.others?.name`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do string interpolation to call an object, but you should call any single property from the object.

```
<h1>{{others}}</h1> // output [object object]


// do like this

<h1>{{others.name}}</h1>
```

And object is not a something that you can iterate

Answer (score 0):

You’ll have to add the “key value” pipe for you to be able to use *ngFor with objects.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
    Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value}}</b>
</div>
```